# svn dropbox checkout fails

Tags: svn

I've got my subversion repositories on dropbox.  I want to check out on a server where I rent space and can't install my full dropbox directory.  I got a dropbox sharing link, but svn checkout said the URL was not properly encoded.  I encoded the URL but then I get the following.  (URL modified for privacy.)

svn: OPTIONS of 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r1XXXXXXXy5a/AXXXXXpzu-G0ybr7RzlHea%3Fdl%3D0': 200 OK (https://www.dropbox.com)

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about your setup? What URL are you using for checkouts? What svn server are you running? How is Dropbox involved in this? I have a feeling that what you want to do is not something Subversion can support. SVN and Dropbox have problems playing together because SVN assumes that the repo is one and only one location. However, I can't tell with what you stated so far.

Comment: The URL I posted was my argument to checkout.  Apparently, svn is expecting either a file or the URL of a subversion server which dropbox is not.  So it won't work.  Seems a mini-server than translates svn requests <===> http requests would be a useful thing.

Comment: Dropbox isn't a Subversion server. The `http://` should point to an Apache `httpd` server compiled to be able to run the `mod_dav_svn` and `mod_dav` plugins -- plus a few other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Dropbox with Subversion that way. To use Apache `httpd` with Subversion, you need to compile Apache `httpd` with certain libraries, and you need to configure the `httpd.conf` with the `mod_dav_svn` and `mod_dav` plugins. Plus, you need to configure your repository and security information.

What can you do?

**Use Git instead**: I am not one of those *Subversion sux, Git rulz* people. But, when you have network issues, Git will work since the repository is always on the local machine. In this case, you put your Git repo under your Dropbox. However, you don't use that repository directly. Instead, you *clone*, *push*, and *pull* from it.

***Misuse Dropbox and Subversion and Hope for the Best***: Not recommended, but...

On your local machine, run `svnserve` to setup the Subversion server daemon. There's no guarantee `svnserve` is on the server you're renting space on, but fortunately, it is usually included in Subversion clients anyway. You need to update the `conf/svnserve.conf` file in your repository to either allow anonymous commits, or to use that `passwd` file as your user/password database (I recommend the latter. If you do the latter, add yourself as a user in that `passwd` file).

Then do checkouts with `svn://localhost/...`, do your work, and commit.

The problem is that the Subversion repository simply doesn't understand that it can be in multiple locations at once, so it offers no protection if two users are using two different `svnserve` processes to connect to the repository that happens to be on two different computers at the same time thanks to Dropbox.

People have used this configuration, and they have had success, but be warned that you cannot run `svnserve` on two different machines to point to the same Dropbox repository on two different machines, and then checkout and commit changes at the same time.

Comment: What if there is one committer and possibly multiple readers.  Might svn + dropbox work there?

Comment: I can't even guarantee Dropbox/SVN combo working with a single user. You can try it. However, all the users should be talking the same `svnserve` process on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

#### DropBox + SVN seems to have improved

I tried before and then realized it's not working; now I'm using it without problems and I'd like to know if I'm just lucky or something has really changed. As a single user, in theory, syncing with DropBox should never cause locking problems - it did before, but looks like not anymore.

**There's a chance they fixed it.**
Anyone who knows something about this, please let us svn-using guys know.
I'm going to update this post whenever I find out something.